# partial power sums in finite fields

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

I am thinking about the following problem:

Let $p$ be a prime and let $A \subset (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ be an arbitrary non-empty subset. Let $N \subset \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}$. For $n \in N$ consider the sums
\begin{align*}
s_n= \sum_{a \in A}a^n
\end{align*}
I'm curious to see if something can be said about the sizes of $A$ and $N$ if all of the $s_n=0$. As a simple example, suppose $\vert N \vert >(p+1)/2$ (I think this can probably be relaxed a lot), then $\vert A \vert >2$. Clearly $A$ can't contain one element. If $A$ contains two elements, say $a,b$, then since $\vert N \vert >2$, we can find consecutive integers $n, n+1 \in N$. Then since $a^n+b^n=0$ we see that $b=\zeta a$ for some $\zeta$ with $\zeta^n=-1$. Using the $n+1$ equation implies that $\zeta^{n+1}=\zeta^n$ which is impossible.

Some google searching has yielded a lot of estimates for the sizes of solution sets to these (and more general) diagonal equations, i.e. the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}-$ rational points on the curves cut out by the polynomials
\begin{align*}
f_n(x_1,\dots, x_m)=\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^n, \ \ \ m=\vert A \vert
\end{align*}

but I have yet to find estimates on the sizes of the intersections of the associated curves. Any references or insights will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is the case of $p\equiv1\pmod3$ with $A$ consisting of the third roots of unity (so $|A|=3$) when $s_n=0$ as long as $n$ is not divisible by three. Larger cyclic (multiplicative) subgroups can be used similarly. There is trade off in a sense that larger $A$ allows a denser set of exponents.

Comment: As an extreme case consider $A=\{1,p-1\}$ and $N$ consisting of all the odd exponents. My first comment extends that from second roots of unity to higher ones. Of course, a coset of a group of roots of unity can be used equally well.

Comment: Right. Thank you for your response. I need some time to think about this but there is a conjecture here along the lines of " $A$ must be a union of cosets of $m$-th roots of unity where $m$ is some multiple of the greatest common divisor of the $(p-1)/(p-1,n)$ for $n \in N$.